# Split irregular measured data into time intervals

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a measurement device that shows whether a system is ON (1) or OFF (0) with the associated time stamp (STATS_DATE). I need to calculate the total number of minutes the system was ON during a 15-minute interval. The system is capable of being ON or OFF for hours at a time.

**Example of data.**

[image: Measured in first two columns, desired output on the other two columns.]

I can easily calculate overall durations but I'm having issues when it spans over multiplate Interval Data segments. As in, if it ran for several hours having the continuous runtimes showing 15 minutes.

Comment: To make the data useful **edit your question** to post it as **text**, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also include your own efforts at solving this.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in PowerQuery, DAX Measure, DAX Calculated Column, or Excel cell formula? What will determine the range of `Interval Data` column?

Comment: How did you come up with `4.28`?

Comment: 10:08:32 (off) - 10:04:15 (on) = 4 mins & 17 secs ==> 17 secs = 0.28 mins (17/60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate method in Powerquery

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
xtable=Table.Buffer(Table.FromColumns({List.Alternate(Source[STATS DATE],1,1,1)}&{List.Alternate(Source[STATS DATE],1,1)})),
min = DateTime.From(Number.RoundDown(Number.From(List.Min(xtable[Column1])) * 96) / 96),
max = DateTime.From(Number.RoundUp(Number.From(List.Max(xtable[Column2])) * 96) / 96),
count = Number.RoundUp(Duration.TotalMinutes(max - min) / 15) ,
IntervalTable = Table.FromList(List.DateTimes(min, count, #duration(0,0,15,0)), Splitter.SplitByNothing(), type table[ IntervalStart = DateTime.Type ] ),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(IntervalTable, "IntervalEnd", each [IntervalStart]+#duration(0,0,15,0),type datetime),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom","match",(x)=>Table.SelectRows(xtable, each 
    Number.From([Column1])<=Number.From(x[IntervalStart]) and Number.From([Column2])>=Number.From(x[IntervalStart])  or 
    Number.From([Column2])<Number.From(x[IntervalEnd]) and Number.From([Column2])>=Number.From(x[IntervalStart]) or 
    Number.From([Column1])>=Number.From(x[IntervalStart]) and Number.From([Column1])<=Number.From(x[IntervalEnd]) )),
#"Expanded match" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "match", {"Column1", "Column2"}, {"Column1", "Column2"}),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded match", "Custom", each if [Column1]=null then 0 else Duration.TotalMinutes(List.Min({[IntervalEnd],[Column2]})-List.Max({[IntervalStart],[Column1]}))),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom2", {"IntervalEnd"}, {{"Duration", each List.Sum([Custom]), type number}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

| STATS DATE | ON/OFF |
| --- | --- |
| 04/07/2023 10:04:15 AM | 1 |
| 04/07/2023 10:08:32 AM | 0 |
| 04/07/2023 10:17:20 AM | 1 |
| 04/07/2023 10:20:20 AM | 0 |
| 04/07/2023 10:33:19 AM | 1 |
| 04/07/2023 10:36:19 AM | 0 |
| 04/07/2023 10:57:58 AM | 1 |
| 04/07/2023 11:00:58 AM | 0 |
| 04/07/2023 11:27:36 AM | 1 |
| 04/07/2023 11:31:02 AM | 0 |
| 04/07/2023 11:34:02 AM | 1 |
| 04/07/2023 11:37:02 AM | 0 |
| 04/07/2023 01:37:04 PM | 1 |
| 04/07/2023 02:05:06 PM | 0 |
| 04/07/2023 02:50:59 PM | 1 |
| 04/07/2023 02:56:09 PM | 0 |
| 04/07/2023 02:59:09 PM | 1 |
| 04/07/2023 03:02:31 PM | 0 |

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PowerQuery solution:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Add On DT" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "OnDT", each if [#"ON/OFF"] = 1 then [STATS DATE] else null, type datetime),
    #"Add Off DT" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add On DT", "OffDT", each if [#"ON/OFF"] = 1 then #"Added Index"{[Index]}[STATS DATE] else null, type datetime),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Add Off DT", each [OnDT] <> null and [OnDT] <> ""),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"OnDT", "OffDT"}),
    #"Add 15 mins blocks" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Blocks", each 
      let
        min = DateTime.From(Number.RoundUp(Number.From([OnDT]) * 96) / 96),
        max = DateTime.From(Number.RoundUp(Number.From([OffDT]) * 96) / 96),
        steps = Number.RoundUp(Duration.TotalMinutes(max - min) / 15) + 1
      in
        List.DateTimes(min, steps, #duration(0,0,15,0))
    ),
    #"Expanded Blocks" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Add 15 mins blocks", "Blocks"),
    #"Add Minutes" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Blocks", "Minutes", each Duration.TotalMinutes( List.Min({[OffDT], [Blocks] }) - List.Max({[OnDT], [Blocks]-#duration(0,0,15,0)}) ), type number),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Add Minutes", {"Blocks"}, {{"Minutes", each List.Sum([Minutes]), type number}}),
    DataReady = #"Grouped Rows",
    #"Generate series" = 
      let
        min = List.Min(DataReady[Blocks]),
        max = List.Max(DataReady[Blocks]),
        steps = Number.RoundUp(Duration.TotalMinutes(max - min) / 15) + 1
      in
        Table.FromValue(List.DateTimes(min, steps, #duration(0,0,15,0)), [DefaultColumnName = "Interval Data"]),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Generate series", {"Interval Data"}, DataReady, {"Blocks"}, "Data", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Data", {"Minutes"}, {"Minutes"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Data",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Minutes"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"Interval Data", type datetime}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Result
[image]